# Meaning of 再生の日

Tags: meaning

I have a question about what 再生の日 means in the context of the following sentence: "全ては再生の日のために." I've gathered that 再生 means regenerate or recycle, but I have a feeling this doesn't mean recycling day and I can't find any help for this on Google thus far. Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context but I guess "全ては再生の日のために" is a phrase in a game or an anime. If so, it should be `revival` or `reincarnation` because 再 is 'again' or 're-' and 生 can be 'live' or 'born'.

Answer (score 1):

It means all is for the sake of the day when the person will be reborn/resurrected. http://jisho.org/search/%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F for a dictionary source.